# laravel combine two csv's without overwriting similar data in each one

Tags: laravel, csv

In excel, there is a function called "paste special -> skip empty cells"..and essentially what this does is it allows you to take two csv's, each containing the same columns, and paste different data into the spreadsheet without overwriting existing data. I need to try and replicate this in PHP.

I have 3 machines, each running being used to examine a student at a different phase of their exam. Machine 1 will have a data column like "name=Adam, exam1=pass, exam2=null, exam3=null". Machine 2 will have "name=Adam, exam1=null, exam2=pass, exam3=null", and Machine 3, as you can guess will be "name=Adam, exam1=null, exam2=null, exam3=pass". Now, in Excel, I can just copy paste machine 1 into machine 2 using "skip empty" and it'll result in "name=Adam, exam1=pass, exam2=pass, exam3=null". Then copy the new file from machine 2 into machine 3 and it'll give me the students full result of "name=Adam, exam1=pass, exam2=pass, exam3=pass". However, I'm having to do this on 10-15 machines. I would like to find a way to automate this.

I've tried using this code in my blade:

```
        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">CSV Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="csv_import[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
        <br/><br/>
        <label for="exampleFormControlFile2">CSV Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="csv_import[]" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile2">
        <br/><br/>

        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Import' class="btn btn-primary">
```

Here is my controller:

```
  public function combineCSV(Request $request){
    $csv = request('csv_import');
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        $path = $request->file($csv[0])->store('excel-files');
        $products = (new FastExcel)->import($request->file($path), function ($line) {
          $student = Student::where('student_id', $line->student_id)->first();
        });
    }

}
```

I know this is very wrong (obviously because i'm getting errors). But i'm not familiar with csv or file manipulation yet. I'm trying to use the FastExcel package on github for laravel, for no reason in particular. If there's a better package, i'm completely down to use it. But how can I upload more than one file, scan each line by line and say "if exam1 == null && csv->exam1 == null, continue, else if exam1 == null && csv->exam1 == pass, update record".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes in the future, here's how I solved it.

```
  $csv = request('csv_import');
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($csv); $i++){ //loop through all csv's
      $file = fopen($csv[$i],"r");
          $c = 0;
          while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',')) !== FALSE) { //iterate over each line
            if($c == 0){ //if first line of csv contains headers, skip first line
              $c++;
              continue;
            } else { //search for student by 3 identifying criteria
              $student = Combine::where('fname', $data[1])->
                                  where('lname', $data[2])->
                                  where('student_number', $data[3])->first();

              if($student){ //if student exists, check that field in csv is null and that new csv contains data where existing csv contains no data
                  if ($student->test1 == NULL && $data[4] != NULL){
                   $student->test1 = $data[4];
               }
              if ($student->test2 == NULL && $data[5] != NULL){
                  $student->test2 = $data[5];
              }              
              $student->save();
            } else { //if student not found, create new one
              $student = new Student();
              $student->fname = $data[1];
              $student->lname = $data[2];
              $student->student_number = $data[3];
              $student->test1 = $data[4];
              $student->test2 = $data[5];
              $student->save();
            }
          }
          }

          fclose($file);
    }
      return Excel::download(new CombineExport, 'combined.csv');

}
```